# Subclassing dict to give it inital values from a JSON file doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, subclassing

I come from a C/C++ background

I would like to subclass dict to make one that automatically opens a JSON file.
Here's the code and problem:

```
class DictFromJSON(dict):
    def get_from_file(self, filename):
        with open(filename,) as file_reader:
            self = json.load(file_reader)
        print(self)

    def save(self, filename):
        with open(filename, "w") as file_writer:
            json.dump(self, file_writer)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        super().__setitem__(key, value)
        self.save()

    def __init__(self, filename, *args):
        super().__init__(args)
        self.get_from_file(filename)

json_dict = DictFromJSON("myjson.json")
print(json_dict)
```

The JSON file for testing contains a single variable mykey

this outputs:

```
{'mykey': True}
{}
```

So it's opening the file correctly, `print(self)` outputs the expected results, but when I print a variable made with the class it's still empty.

I've tried assigning `self` from `json.load()` a few different ways, including iterating through keys, but that didn't work either

Comment: Regarding `self = json.load...`, see [Are Python variables pointers? Or else, what are they?](/q/13530998/4518341)

Comment: Regarding subclassing `dict`, see [How to properly subclass dict](/q/2390827/4518341), specifically [andrew pate's answer](/a/49499084/4518341) (`UserDict`).

Comment: @wjandrea Thanks for the links. In my understanding then, `self=json.load()` assigns the name "self" to the output of json.load(), instead of copying the contents of load() to whatever "self" was previously bound to.

As for `UserDict`, I already looked into it but probably should have mentioned that i'm using CircuitPython, which has a partial implementation of `collections` that does not include `UserDict`

Answer (score 1):

Assigning to the local name `self` does not update the object. You need to use `update`:

```
class DictFromJSON(dict):
    def get_from_file(self, filename):
        with open(filename,) as file_reader:
            self.update(json.load(file_reader))

    def save(self, filename):
        with open(filename, "w") as file_writer:
            json.dump(self, file_writer)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        super().__setitem__(key, value)
        self.save()

    def __init__(self, filename, *args):
        super().__init__(args)
        self.get_from_file(filename)
```

Comment: `cls(json.load...)` in `__new__` should get you infinite recursion. "super()" is missing.
But whatever: subclassing `dict` this way is prone to quintillions of unwanted edge cases: you should recommend `collections.UserDict` instead. (with all due respect - I know you know this sort of stuff )

Comment: I was under the impression that `UserDict` was primarily used before it was possible to subclass `dict` (though I'm aware there are still documented use-cases for it). I didn't really want to get into a discussion about, say, inheritance vs composition, though composition is probably a better way to do. I'll fix the lazy omission of `super`; I had class methods on the brain :)

Comment: One might also look at the source code for the `shelf` module, and write something similar that uses JSON, rather than `pickle`, to perform the on-the-fly serialization.

Comment: Yes - it is probably possible to just subclass something in "shelve". (I was even revisiting it today after seeing something around about `tinyDB`)

Comment: UserDict will funnel all dictionary methods through the user's custom `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` - while inheriting from `dict` requires one to customize each method from `get`, `setdefault`, `__getitem__` and so on, as each of those is independent from `__get/set/del/item__`. This is the major difference. I too found out it to still be useful just a little while ago. OTOH, not inheriting from dict makes cls do not work directly with `json.encode` (but there are even further caveats there)

Comment: Thanks for the solutions chepner. I can assume the benefits of trying to create `DictFromJson` directly from the output of `json.load(...)`, however it didn't seem to work. The first solution did though, so I will settle for `update()`.

I should have mentioned it before but I need to use this class in both normal python and CircuitPython, the latter of which doesn't implement `UserDict`, which I why I'm working directly off `dict`

Comment: Oh, I forgot, it's `dict.__init__`, not `dict.__new__`, that copies key/value pairs from an existing dict into the new dict, so you were right to begin with :) I'll just delete that part from the answer.